# Different number of events and experiment sessions in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have an experiment on a page that works like this: when a user clicks a specific link on the page I'm redirecting him to the original page or to the new one. It's made on click event via JS. It's [a server-side experiment](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-server-side), meaning that I manually on my server choose variation, mark users in the experiment and then send experiment data to GA via JS.

On the click on the link I'm sending the following event via JS to GA in order to track the experiment (and similar for B variant):

```
ga(
  'send',
  'event',
  'A/B Test',
  'Some test',
  'Variant A',
  {
      expId: 'experimentID',
      expVar: 0,
      nonInteraction: true
  }
);
```

Since this event gets sent specifically for this experiment and there are no other events on the page that are sending the experiment data, I'm assuming that number of such events and experiment sessions in GA should be the same, but it's not. Here is real data:

**Events**

- Total Events

  - Variant A -- 4,862
  - Variant B -- 3,876
- Unique Events

  - Variant A -- 3,799
  - Variant B -- 3,504

**Experiment sessions**

- Variant A -- 9,153
- Variant B -- 9,312

All data was taken for the same date range and it's based on 100% sessions according to GA.

As I understand, number of experiment sessions should be equal to number of unique events, but it's nowhere close. I have many other experiments and this data is always different in either direction.

What can cause this divergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in the report can be a difference because Experiment ID and Variant — are [user-scoped dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=content_experiments&jump=ga_experimentvariant).

It means these parameters [will be applied to current and all the following sessions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828).